# Open Google Maps from Flutter with place selected

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I am trying to open Google Maps with a place selected. Can the below url be used with dynamic data? The one that I am using selects the first place I searched for on Google Maps. What else do I need to change or is this the right way to open Google Maps from Flutter?

I am using Url Launcher:

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
```

Code:

```
name = Uri.encodeComponent(name);
name = name.replaceAll('%20', '+');

String googleUrl =
    'https://www.google.com/maps/place/$name/@$latitude,$longitude,3z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1s$name!3m4!1s0x89c259ae9485299b:0x8b3fcf671f63ac6b!8m2!3d$latitude!4d$longitude';
print(googleUrl);
if (await canLaunch(googleUrl)) {
  await launch(googleUrl);
} else {
  throw 'Could not open the map.';
}
```

I noticed that each place has a `place_id`. Can that be used to target specific place?

--- Solution thanks to comment below ---

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52052232/flutter-url-launcher-google-maps

Comment: You might want to consider using [Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/). For example, using the `query_place_id` parameter you can search for a place using a `place_id`

Comment: Thank you. Very easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading this [doc for Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme#search). You can define the center area with a lat/long and the place's name on the URL. This should center the place on the configured coordinates. The URL that you can use should be similar to:

`comgooglemaps://?q=$name&center=$lat,$long`